# Choose right QML class for blind typing trainer

Tags: c++, qml, text-editor

I am developing QML blind typing trainer and can't figure out, which one of QML classes I should use to display text. I need some kind of text editor, with cursor fixed in particular place, when user inputs correct symbol, whole text moves one symbol left.

I've tried out TextEdit and TextArea for this purposes, but I can't figure out, how to make them work.
Here is an example of the behaviour I want to achieve: [example](https://ukanabastreet.github.io/blind-type/#/lessons/11)

Comment: Probably the simplest way would be to implement a custom control. If you do it in C++ or QML directly is up to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `TextEdit` is absolutely useless here, since you don't actually edit the text. As @iam_peter already said above you probably have to implement the control by yourself.

For example like this:

```js
Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400
    title: "Typing trainer"

    Rectangle {
        id: outer
        height: 40
        width: 400
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        radius: 5
        border.width: 2
        border.color: "#999"
        color: "#eaf2f8"
        clip: true
        focus: true

        Keys.onPressed: (event)=>
                        {
                            var ch = event.text;
                            if(ch === container.getChar())
                            {
                                container.position ++;
                            }
                        }

        Row
        {
            id: container
            property string text: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
            property int position: 0
            x: (outer.width / 2 - metrics1.width)

            function getChar()
            {
                return container.text[container.position];
            }

            Text {
                id: block1
                text: container.text.substring(0, container.position)
                font.pointSize: 24
                color: "#333"
            }
            TextMetrics {
                id: metrics1
                text: block1.text
                font: block1.font
            }
            Text {
                id: block2
                text: container.text.substring(container.position)
                font.pointSize: 24
                color: "#999"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nitpick: the row `x` and `nextChar` could just be bindings, no need for functions here.

Comment: you're absolutely right, thanks @GrecKo, I've updated the code